# Showing number of poles of $f$ equals number of zeros of $f-A$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification

I have a claim I wish to prove that says that if $f$ is meromorphic on $B(0,1)$, continuous on a neighborhood of $\partial B(0,1)$, $$A>\sup_{\partial B(0,1)}|f|$$ then the number of zeros of $f-A$ on $B(0,1)$ equals the number of poles of $f$ on $B(0,1)$.

Could someone verify my proof of that claim. I'd also love it if you could give me tips to improve the proof, or tell me what I'm doing wrong.

$\textbf{Proof:}$

Since $f$ is continuous in a nieghborhood of $\partial B(0,1)$, say $V$, by shrinking $V$ is necessary we may assume that $f$ is continuous on $\text{cl}(V)$. Since $f$ is continuous on the compact set $\text{cl}(V)$ it is uniformly continuous on the same set. Then it is uniformly continuous on $V$. Since $|f|<A$ on $\partial B(0,1)$ by uniform continuity it follows that for some $0<r<1$ we have $|f|<A$ on $\partial B(0,r)$. This also implies $f$ has no poles on $\partial B(0,r)$, so since it is meromorphic on $B(0,1)$ it therefore must be analytic on $\partial B(0,r)$. Then $f-A$ is meromorphic on $B(0,r)$ analytic on the boundary, so by the argument principle we have
$$\int_{\partial B(0,r)}d\arg(f-A)=N_0-N_\infty$$
where $N_0$ is the number of zeros of $f-A$ on $B(0,r)$ and $N_\infty$ the number of poles. As $|f|<A$ It follows that $f(z)-A$ stays in a single half-plane for $|z|=r$, and so the increase in argument around $\partial B(0,r)$ for $f-A$ is zero. Then
$$0=\int_{\partial B(0,r)}d\arg(f-A)=N_0-N_\infty$$
So $N_0=N_\infty.$ As $A$ is constant it follows that on $B(0,r)$ $f-A$ and $f$ have the same number of poles, therefore
$$N_0=\#\{\text{ poles of }f\text{ on }B(0,r)\}$$
By uniform continuity and our choice of $r$ it follows that
$$\#\{\text{ poles of }f\text{ on }B(0,r)\}=\#\{\text{ poles of }f\text{ on }B(0,1)\}$$
So
$N_0=\#\{\text{ poles of }f\text{ on }B(0,1)\}$
Which is our desired result.$\blacksquare$